# Preferred status bar style on iPad multitasking - split screen

Tags: ios, iphone, split-screen-multitasking

I have two view controllers - the first has a `UIStatusBarStyleDefault`, the second has a `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

VC1 is presenting VC2 as a modal form sheet. So when presenting in regular trait collection, VC2 is presented as `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` and VC1 sets the status bar to **Default**.
But in compact trait collection, VC2 is fullscreen and sets the status bar style to **Light Content**.

The problem is when switching between regular to compact (full screen to form sheet) the status bar is not updating.

[image: Full Split Screen]

Trying -
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
after trait collection change did not solve the issue.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This controls whether this view controller takes over control of the status bar's appearance when presented non-full screen on another view controller. Defaults to NO.

@available(iOS 7.0, *)
public var modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance: Bool
```

Usage:

```
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .FormSheet
navigationController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```

Once that's set the root view controller of that navigation controller can override the preferredStatusBarStyle()